# How to loop through dynamically add Fields in Angular.js and get data and send it to the server?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code for adding input fields dynamically
 the HTML

```
    <div ng-app="timeTable" ng-controller="addCoursesCtrl">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addNewCourse()">Add New Course</button><br/><br/> 
        <fieldset ng-repeat="choice in choices">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option>Lab</option>
                        <option>Theory</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Course Name" name="" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <br/>
        </fieldset>
        <h2>
            {{choice}}
        </h2>
    </div>
```

the js

```
timeTable.controller("addCoursesCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.choices = [{id:'choice1'},{id:'choice2'}];
    $scope.addNewCourse = function () {
        var newITemNo = $scope.choices.length + 1;
        $scope.choices.push({ 'id': 'choice' + newITemNo });
    };
});
```

in my controller every time you click addnewCourse button ,it adds new choise to the array ,and in my html I use ng-repeat to add the need input,but my problem how to take the data and put in array as object my prefrerd object is array of 
[{"Course":value..,"Type":value....},{"Course":value..,"Type":value....}]
and send it to the server in this shape, so how the preferd way to do so ,the course value from the input feild ,and type value from select.

Answer (score 0):

The data you want to send to the server can be bound directly to the view with ng-model.

Define the data that the server needs (eventually, do this in a service):

```
$scope.choices = [{id:'choice1', course:'', type:''},{id:'choice2', course:'', type:''}];
```

In the view:

```
...
<fieldset ng-repeat="choice in choices">
    ...
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Course Name" name=""
        ng-model="choice.course"
        class="form-control" />
    ...
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="choice.type">
        <option>Lab</option>
        <option>Theory</option>
    </select>
    ...
```

Convert to json to send to the server:

```
var asJson = angular.toJson($scope.choices);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a `ngModel` to the select and input. First, create a scope variable with an empty array:

```
$scope.formData = [];
```

Then, in your markup, add the `ng-model` in the repeat and use the `$index` variable to track the array:

```
<fieldset ng-repeat="choice in choices">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <select ng-model="formData[$index].Type" class="form-control">
                <option>Lab</option>
                <option>Theory</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input ng-model="formData[$index].Course" type="text" placeholder="Enter Course Name" name="" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
</fieldset>
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3apL78v5/1/)